# Why can the discretization of continuous models lead to different qualitative behaviour?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I was asked to explain this phenomenon using the example of logistic model during the next class (online of course). I do not have problems with analyzing both types of logistic model and I can certainly say the behavior differs, especially since

$$p_{n+1}=p_n+rp_n(1-p_n)$$

produces chaotic behavior for $r=4$. However I still struggle with answering the question WHY. It always appeared to me as a question more of philosophical nature rather than mathematical. I have always done the math and take my results for granted if my analysis was rigorous, that meant my solution / final result is right, that's it. I did not see a need for deeper understanding, nevertheless now I am forced to think it over ;)). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Different discretizations of the same ODE can lead to different qualitative behavior. Not talking about step size.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of the right side in $\dot y=f(y)$, then the Euler method gives somewhat correct results for step sizes up to $r=0.1/L$ and a somewhat qualitatively correct behavior up to $r=1/L$. For the given $f(y)=y(1-y)$ you get $f'(y)=1-2y$ and thus $L=1$ on the interval $[0,1]$. This means that the step sizes where the discretization is still at least marginally related to the original ODE are all in the "boring" region of the logistic map where it has one attracting (non-zero) fixed point and no cycles.

$$
p_{n+1}=p_n+rp_n(1-p_n)=p_n(1+r-p_n)\implies\frac{p_{n+1}}{1+r}=(1+r)\cdot\frac{p_n}{1+r}\left(1-\frac{p_n}{1+r}\right)
$$

Conversely, in the region of the parameter $r$ where the logistic map is "interesting" with branching limit cycles and chaotic behavior it has no longer any relation to the discretization of the logistic ODE.

Comment: Where does the fact that it gives correct results for $0.1/L$ comes from? Is it checked empirically or is there some dependence between parameters and Lipschitz  constatnt, that is universal for Euler method?

Comment: That is just general experience. The other, 1/L, is related to the stability region of the method which is a circle of radius 1 around -1. In theory for the scalar case r<2/L should also be possible but will increasingly oscillate around the exact solution.

Comment: Can you recommend any literature available online where I can find derivation of this method with the stability region part included? I am struggling to find something valuable, most of the websites either just state the method or derive it not rigorously.

Comment: Hairer-Wanner: *"Solving ODE II: Stiff and DAE"* contains an extensive discussion of stability regions for different stability concepts.